# Hide the exception stacktrace from logs depending on log level

Tags: java, spring

Let's say we have 2 projects: project A and B

**Project A**

This project defines some common exceptions. Doesn't have the slf4j dependency.
An example of Exception

```
public abstract class SomeException extends RuntimeException {

    public SomeException (String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    // just added, being able to hide the stacktrace, but it contains an additional param
    public SomeException (String msg, boolean suppressStacktrace) {
        super(msg, null, suppressStacktrace, !suppressStacktrace);
    }

}
```

**Project B**

This is the main project. It includes the **Project A** dependency, and it calls the defined
**SomeException** in a lot of places. This project includes the slf4j dependency, and contains the slf4j config where we specify the logging level. I want to display the stacktrace just if the log level is DEBUG.

**The challenge**

I have a lot of usages of **throw new SomeException(String msg)**, and I would like to hide the stacktrace in the Project A, based on the log level of the parent project Project B without changing the exception signature, as I will have to change it in 100 places. I am not able to have 2 super calls  in a if/else statement. So the final change would look like:

```
public SomeException (String msg) {
    // how to get the surpressStackTrace param from the parent project config?
    this(msg, surpressStackTrace);
}
```

If this approach is not right, what other possibilities I have to hide the stacktrace without changing the called exception signature?

Note: these exceptions are non blocking. Even if the exception occurs, the flow is not interrupted. Can I use **@ControllerAdvice** so that after the exception is handled, the flow is continued?

I also tried this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ControllerAdvisor.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(SomeException .class)
    public void handleSomeException(SomeException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, ex.getMessage());

        if(Level.DEBUG.equals(logger.getLevel())){
            logger.log(Level.DEBUG, ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

However, this terminates the execution of the further logic. Is it possible to continue the flow after the exception is handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question...

But here is a possible solution:

- Ignores `SomeException` (you can because it is a RuntimeException)
- Keeps the normal execution process.
- Logs when the exception was thrown, with stack trace when log-level is `DEBUG` and without when the log-level is not `DEBUG`

This could be done with an `Aspect`

1. Make sure you have spring-aop on your classpath; for spring-boot, you can include `spring-boot-starter-aop` as dependency.
2. Enable AOP by adding `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to one of your configuration classes.
3. Write a `@Around`-advise to intercept all the methods where the exception can occur. Do a try-catch, but proceed with the normal execution of the code when a `SomeException` is thrown.
4. Log the message with or without the stack trace based on the log level.

This could look something like this:

```java
package com.example.demo.aop;

import com.example.demo.exception.SomeException;
import org.aspectj.lang.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.slf4j.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class DemoAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoAspect.class);
    
    // all executed public method-calls in the package com.example.demo
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(public * com.example.demo..*(..))")
    private void pointcut(){
    }


    // intercept the defined pointcut
    @Around("pointcut()")
    public Object ignoreSomeException(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result =  pjp.proceed(); // <-- try normal execution
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            log(e);
            result =  pjp.proceed(); // <-- continue normal execution
        } finally {
            return result;
        }
    }
    
    // Log the exception based on the loglevel
    private void log(Throwable e) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e); // <-- log with stacktrace
        } else {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());    // <-- only log the message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't think about aop

Comment: I will try it and I will accept the answer later

Comment: @AndrewT did you try it? Was this answer useful?